# htaccess rewrite URL with multiple php parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So this is likely a duplicate, but I have exhausted every example on here and nothing works.

I am working on an adult site for someone, and using it as an excuse to learn something along the way.

Take this URL:
http://www.websitename.co.uk/profiles/masseur/profile.php?id=5&name=Erika%20S

I want it to look like this:
http://www.websitename.co.uk/profiles/masseur/Erika_S

So 2 things need to happen:

- URL rewrite without being redirected, disregarding the id parameter
- spaces in the name being replaced with an underscore (or a dash)

Rewrite is on. Other rewrites work such as removing file extensions (is this interfering? Although it don't work even if I disable this.)

I am losing whatever hair I have left.

please help!

Comment: So, to understand what exactly you want: User should type "http://www.websitename.co.uk/profiles/masseur/Erika_S" into their address bar, and then you bring back the page at "http://www.websitename.co.uk/profiles/masseur/profile.php?id=5&name=Erika%20S" ? (if that is the case, you will not be able to do that with url redirect, because there is no way for it to know what your _id_ variable should be, closest you can get will be "http://www.websitename.co.uk/profiles/masseur/profile.php?name=Erika%20S"

Comment: I should have been more specific. The first link is the actual URL that appears when a link is clicked. I want it to appear as the 2nd link in the address bar.

Comment: You will have to use javascript for that if you do not want to use a redirect. The rewrite engine on the server side will only interpret URLs coming to the server, and change them before passing them on to your web server application. The only way to change the browser's URL from the server's side is to tell the browser via a redirect response to go to a new URL (redirecting the browser)

Comment: Create a unique column in your database with a *slug*, i.e. a sanitised, lowercased string that is derived from the name. There are loads of example functions that do this. Construct the URLs on your page output from these, then use them for lookups from your rewrite rule. You probably also need the flags `[L,B,QSA]` on your `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know which id to use? You could possibly use a Rewritemap to look it up, but it depends on how you know what it is (As Heinrich pointed out in the comments).

Also translating the '_' to a space, though possible, would be much easier to do in `profile.php` that in the rewrite. What's slightly confusing is you say you want to translate spaces to underscores, but in your example you do the opposite (to encoded spaces at least). Could you clarify, or correct my misunderstanding.

Here is a base rule to start you off

`RewriteRule ^/profiles/masseur/(\w+) /profiles/masseur/profile.php?id=5&name=$1`